# Efficient sum approach

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to do this formula:

=(A1/B1)+(A2/B2)+(A3/B3) an so on until row 356, how can I do it in a shorter way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUM(A1:A356/B1:B356)
```

This is an array formula.  Confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Edit: to add another column:

```
=SUM(A1:A356/B1:B356 + C1:C356)
```

Again it is an array formula so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot, what would be the solution for (A1/B1)+C1+(A2/B2)+C2+(A3/B3)+C3 ?

Comment: @ArturoEsparza just for your information, to do what you asked with @chrisneilson non array formula use `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A356,1/B1:B356) + SUM(C1:C356)`

Answer (score 2):

As a non-array formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A356,1/B1:B356)
```